# How do I pass id from another const to another const in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, axios, get

I have 2 Get API I that I used to read the data. First API I used is to read the student details. In this student details there is ID that I need to read from second API and display the data in the first API

First API is getDetails
Second API is getClass

I want to pass the `e.student_class_id` into the `getClass` after I have got the class name I will pass back the class name at the `getDetails`

```
const getDetails= (infoID) =>
    {
        axios.get(`${apiInfo}student/getDetails?student_id=${infoID}`)
        .then(function (response) { 
            if(response.data.status == 'success')
            {
                
                e = response.data.result;

                //passing this e.student_class_id;
                $('#tabClassName').html(`<div class="col-xl-12 row">
                                            <div class="col-xl-6">
                                                <h6>Class details</h6>
                                                <p>Class :<span class="item"> //and pass the class name here ? </span></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        `);
            }
        });
    }

    const getClass= () =>
    {
        axios.get(`${apiInfo}getClass`)
        .then(function (res) { 
            if(res.data.status == 'success')
                 {
                    res.data.result.map((e) =>{
                         if(e.id == 'how do I pass it the e.student_class_id here ?'){
                             // return``;
                            console.log(e.class_name);
                         }
                    });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you can use session

Comment: session ? How do I pass it with session ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through a few steps.

first you need to return the **e.student_class_id** inside the then method.

second, you need to return the whole **"axios.get..."** chain.

By doing that, your **getDetails** returns a promise, which resolves to the "**e.student_class_id**".

```
    const getDetails = (infoID) => {
  return axios
    .get(`${apiInfo}student/getDetails?student_id=${infoID}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.data.status == "success") {
        e = response.data.result;

        //passing this e.student_class_id;
        $("#tabClassName").html(`<div class="col-xl-12 row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                                            <h6>Class details</h6>
                                            <p>Class :<span class="item"> //and pass the class name here ? </span></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    `);
        return e.student_class_id;
      }
    });
};
```

the result would be something like this :

```
getDetail(1233).then(result=>.... // result is e.student_class_id
```

We also need to edit **getClass** function.

first it has to take the class argument.

then, you if want to use the data you get in the **getClass** somewhere else, you have to return that value inside the then method, and you need to return axios.get. just like getDetail:

```
          const getClass = (classId) => {
  return axios.get(`${apiInfo}getClass`).then(function (res) {
    if (res.data.status == "success") {
      res.data.result.map((e) => {
        if (e.id == "how do I pass it the e.student_class_id here ?") {
          // return``;
          console.log(e.class_name);
        }
      });
    }
    return res; // or anything else that you may need
  });
};
```

finally, you can use those funtions

```
getDetails(123123).then(classId=>getClassId(classId)).then(dataFrom2ndApi=>...)
```

Comment: I dont quite get it the `getDetail(1233).then(result=>.... // result is e.student_class_id` and this part `getDetails(123123).then(classId=>getClassId(classId)).then(dataFrom2ndApi=>...)` where should  I put those line ?

Comment: I got e is not defined when I add the `return e.student_class_id`

Comment: you should put those line whenever you need them, for example you take an "id" from an input, then you use  the last line in my answer with that id. about the error, i edited getDetail function. in the getClass function, its up to you what to return and where to return it, the most important thing is that your return value should be in the "then" method